# Eclipse galileo hangs when opening a large xml file

Tags: xml, eclipse, ide, freeze

I have Eclipse Galileo Build id: 20100218-1602.
The problem I'm facing is:

- with some XML files those which are of lines less than 12K (approx) are opening without any problem
- but I have few files which have 17K lines, size on disk is just 550KB and one file struts-config just 1600 lines, file size 115KB:
  **When I try to open these 2 it took almost 15 to 20 minutes to open**.

Any suggestion would be appreciated so that it can open like any normal files. 
(Java files or js files which are of same lines are opening without any glitch)
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [bug 108806](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=108806) suggests it has to do with formatting performance, which is still present today ([bug 213302](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=213302), for *really* large files, not just for long lines).
See if the issue persists with Helios (3.6) and the latest WTP plugin.

Check also if there is some schema validation taking place (as in [bug 136901](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=136901)).

Comment: Thanks ,I just checked on Helios those files are taking way too much time to open around 15 minutes. same problem I'm using Ubuntu 10.10, 4GB ram core 2 processor so its not the system may be this problem is not fixed for linux verity. I have un-checked all validation for xml file editor in properties. still have this.

Comment: Thanks for edit :) will take care of this next time.
Further I tried the same file in my friend's System and it opened without any delay. platform is same[os,eclipse]. when i watch my system monitor i saw inet_wait_for_connect is it something about validators [I have already unchecked all validation for xml] any clue...

Comment: @rain: maybe there is a difference in proxy and network settings between your Eclipse and the one of your colleagues?

Comment: Marking as Solved I believe some problem might be due to proxy although i have set the proxy as system wide default and eclipse is also using system default.